# Facing issue in fetching state names using carmen gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carmen

Hi I am using `gem 'carmen-rails'` in my app I am having this type of association

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact
  has_one :permanent_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact, :permanent_address
end
```

and in my employess_controller.rb I have define like this:

```
def subregion_options
    render partial: 'subregion_select'
end
```

and in my routes :

```
resources :employees do
    collection do
      get 'subregion_options'
    end
  end
```

In my employees/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
  <label class="form_label">Email</label>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <label class="form_label">Set Ex Employee</label>
  <%= f.check_box :is_active %>  
  <%= f.fields_for :contact do |c| %>    
    <label class="form_label">Address 1</label>  
    <%= c.text_field :current_address1 %> 
    <%= c.country_select :country,:prompt => 'Select Country' %>
    <%= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: c.object.country} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

in  employees/_subregion_select.html.erb

```
<div id="order_state_code_wrapper">
  <% parent_region ||= params[:parent_region] %>
  <% country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) %>

  <% if country.nil? %>
    <em>Please select a country above</em>
  <% elsif country.subregions? %>
    <%= subregion_select(:contact, :state_code, parent_region) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= text_field(:contact, :state_code) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In js file

```
$('select#employee_contact_attributes_country').change(function() {
    selectWrapper = $('#order_state_code_wrapper');
    countryCode = $(this).val();
    url = "/employees/subregion_options?parent_region=" + countryCode;
    selectWrapper.load(url);
  });
```

But its not fetching any states. Please guide how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what result you are getting

Comment: it shows nothing it goes inside this condition `elsif country.subregions? ` but not able to show states accordingly

Comment: try `subregion_select_tag(name, value, parent_region_or_code)`

Comment: its done actually its fetchinbg but its  css is display none so when I had changed it to display:block; it works :)